# Non-stationary Random Fourier Features

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, fourier-transform, random-fourier-features

Random Fourier Features (RFFs) were introduced by A. Rahimi and B. Recht in their 2007 publication [Random Features for Large-Scale Kernel Machines](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrecht/papers/07.rah.rec.nips.pdf). RFFs are based on Bochner's theorem, which applies to stationary kernels on Euclidean spaces i.e. any positive semi-definite function $k$ satisfying
$$
k(x, y) = \kappa(||x - y||), ~\forall~x, y~ \in \mathbb{R}^d.
$$
Bochner's theorem states that such a function can be written as a Fourier transform :
$$
k(x, y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp{\left[i \omega^T (x - y)\right]}\mathbb{P}(d\omega),
$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure. This is an expectation with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ and we can therefore approximate $k$ via Monte-Carlo based on a sample drawn from $\mathbb{P}$.

It turns out that Bochner's theorem can be extended to non-stationary kernels on Euclidean spaces as well. This is known as Yaglom's theorem or the Yaglom-Genton theorem. A non-stationary kernel can therefore also be approximated via a Monte Carlo scheme. This is what is done in a 2017 paper by J-F. Ton et al., [Spatial Mapping with Gaussian Processes and Nonstationary Fourier Features](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05615). **I do not understand the first steps derivation of the Monte Carlo scheme in that paper.**

For some context, Yaglom's theorem says that a non-stationary kernel $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be written as
$$
k(x, y) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d} \exp{\left[i \left( \omega_1 ^T x - \omega_2 ^T y \right) \right]} \mu(d\omega_1, d\omega_2),
$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated to some $f$ which is a positive semi-definite function with bounded variation. This is the same as
$$
k(x, y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d} \exp{\left[i \left( \omega_1 ^T x - \omega_2 ^T y \right) \right]} f(\omega_1, \omega_2)d\omega_1 d\omega_2,
$$
where $f$ is as above.
The authors first claim that $f$ can be written as
$$
f(\omega_1, \omega_2) = g(\omega_1, \omega_2) + g(\omega_2, \omega_1) + g(\omega_1, \omega_1) + g(\omega_2, \omega_2),
$$
where $g$ is some density. **It is not clear to me why there should exist a density $g$ satisfying that.**

Further, the authors then plug in that form for $f$ in the integral. That should lead to
$$
k(x, y) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d} \exp{\left[i \left( \omega_1 ^T x - \omega_2 ^T y \right) \right]} \left( g(\omega_1, \omega_2) + g(\omega_2, \omega_1) + g(\omega_1, \omega_1) + g(\omega_2, \omega_2) \right) d\omega_1 d\omega_2.
$$
The authors obtain instead
$$
k(x, y) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d} \left(\exp{\left[i \left( \omega_1 ^T x - \omega_2 ^T y \right) \right]} + \exp{\left[i \left( \omega_2 ^T x - \omega_1 ^T y \right) \right]} + \exp{\left[i \omega_1 ^T \left(x - y \right) \right]} + \exp{\left[i \omega_2 ^T \left(x - y \right) \right]} \right) \mu(d\omega_1, d\omega_2).
$$
**I do not understand how they get to that expression.** Could someone unblock me ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a chat with some of the authors of [Spatial Mapping with Gaussian Processes and Nonstationary Fourier Features](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05615), and I got to the bottom of the first part of my question.

The authors did not mean that all $f$'s may necessarily be written as this sum of four terms in $g$. They **chose** to place themselves in the settings where $f$ may be written this way (in so-called "symmetrised" form) because in that case the imaginary part disappears automatically when deriving the RFF scheme.

In the **stationary** case, we do not need to "symmetrise" : in fact what is typically done when deriving the RFF scheme is to use the fact that as the kernel is real-valued, $k(x, y) = \text{Re}\left[k(x, y)\right]$ (i.e. its real part). This is what was done in the [original 2007 paper on RFFs by A. Rahimi and B. Recht](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2007/file/013a006f03dbc5392effeb8f18fda755-Paper.pdf), by the way.

In the nonstationary case, this "trick" can be used but you end up with a form of $k$ from which you cannot write the kernel Gram matrix in factorised form...which is a problem since what makes RFFs work is that the kernel Gram matrix can be written in factorised form $\text{K}_{\text{X}} = \Psi \Psi^{\text{T}}$.

On the second part of my question, the problem is mostly a matter of notations : what is meant by $g(\omega_1, \omega_1)$ is $g(\omega_1, \omega_2) \mathbb{1}\{\omega_1 = \omega_2\}$. Likewise for $g(\omega_2, \omega_2)$.

Further : in [a 2015 paper by Samo and Roberts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02236), section 2.3 specifically, it is shown how to derive a RFF scheme for **some** nonstationary kernels without having to assume $f$ can be written as the sum of the four terms in $g$. What the results in this Samo & Roberts paper imply is that not all nonstationary kernels lend themselves to RFFs. This is a clear difference with the stationary case : all stationary kernels may be approximated by RFFs.